# Reading .properties file after filtering (Java)

Tags: maven, filter, properties

I want to use a properties file for some tests (junit) depending on where I launch the tests. To do so I generated the following POM :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Project</groupId>
  <artifactId>Project</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Project</name>

  <properties>
    <main-filters-directory>src/main/filters</main-filters-directory>
    <main-filtered-directory>src/main/config</main-filtered-directory>
  </properties>

  <profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>env-local</id>
    <activation>
        <property>
            <name>env</name>
            <value>local</value>
        </property>
    </activation>
    <properties>
        <env>local</env>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <filters>
            <filter>${main-filters-directory}/local.properties</filter>
        </filters>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${main-filtered-directory}</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
  </profile>

  <profile>
    <id>env-dev</id>
    <activation>
        <property>
            <name>env</name>
            <value>dev</value>
        </property>
    </activation>
    <properties>
        <env>dev</env>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <filters>
            <filter>${main-filters-directory}/dev.properties</filter>
        </filters>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${main-filtered-directory}</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
  </profile>

  <profile>
    <id>filters</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>env</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <filters>
                <filter>${main-filters-directory}/${env}.properties</filter>
            </filters>
        </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20180130</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Then in my code I have something like :

```
        File dir = new File("");
        String rootPath = dir.getAbsolutePath();
        String appConfigPath = rootPath + "/src/main/config/configuration.properties"; 

        Properties configProps = new Properties();
        configProps.load(new FileInputStream(appConfigPath));
        System.out.println(configProps.getProperty("${archivePort}"));
```

Then I run the project with "mvn -Denv=local test"
But the System.out.println output is "null"

Am I missing something ? 
I know I could use Spring to get the value with the @value annotation but I don't think it's the problem here

local.properties :

```
hostAdress=localhost
archivePort=11114
```

configuration.properties :

```
hostAdress=${hostAdress}
archivePort=${archivePort}
```

Thank you for any answers !

Vaclav